# A RESTful webservice to distribute ZIP/JAR files?

Tags: android, web-services, rest, distribution, package-managers

[Just asking before doing it myself with Ruby and Sinatra...]

I have to publish/distribute a few hundreds small JAR and ZIP files that will be used by an Android application as "freely downloadable content packages".

Each JAR/ZIP will contain a couple of images, a small SQLite DB (or a dump... still to be decided) and a XML or JSON config file. Each file will be from a few hundreds Kb to 2 - 5 Mbs in size. Each file will be download with the Android standard Download Manager and extracted to the external storage of the application (the SD Card) while maintaining the original tree structure of the JAR/ZIP file. From this point on, my application will take care of it in an application-specific way.

I need a server-side solution to publish these file. That is: an online service/repository or a server-side installable program that implements this same kind of service (Possibly Ruby/Sinatra/Padrino, Python/Bootle/Flask or something like that. No Java, please).

The required system will mainly have to:

1. Respond to a GET request directed to a public server directory URL with a list of the files that reside in the given directory (that is: "directory listing"). It would be very nice to have some kind of "rich directory listing" with file descriptions and other metadata (public service so no security/authentication is required). A RSS/Atom feed would probably be nice for this task, as well. In particular if the RSS/Atom engine would be able to extract the file description from a manifest inside the file itself and use it to compile the directory listing. I can accomodate my code to comply with such a file structure.
2. Respond to a GET request directed to a specific file URL with the file itself ("download") (public service so no security/authentication is required).
3. Accept a PUT request writing the upload file into the directory indicated in the URL ("upload") (some simple authentication/security should probably be enforced here, just to prevent vandalism).

As you can see, I'm just looking for a simple HTTP RESTful file server (plus some enriched directory listing).

Does anybody knows of a free online service that can be used (or abused...) for such a task?

Does anybody knows of a (almost)-ready-to-use server-side software solution?

And, of course, any consideration/opinion/suggestion will be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The nearest thing I was able to find is "pulp":

http://www.pulpproject.org/

Unfortunately:

1. It just manages RPM files. It would be possible to develop a plugin for other types of packages but the docu is still missing and the whole project seem to be still moving quickly. We are in a hurry and we do not have time to reverse engineer an existing plugin, create our one and keep it up-to-date with the rest of the system.
2. It just offers a command-line interface. Wonderful for developers but awful for our customers. We need a GUI but we do not have the time to develop it.

So here the usual, old-fashioned, proven solution:

1. Put all of your stuff on a FTP-visible partition.
2. Tweak with the Unix permissions in order to get the level of public access you need (most likely something like "root" or "ftpuser" ownership with 644 permissions)
3. Wrtite a script that generates a file with the metadata describing the content of the other files (taking the metadata from the files themselves or from other source of information). Put this script in a CRON schedule (Unix "at" command) and execute it once per hour or something like that.
4. Access the FTP partition from the client-side via anonymous FTP (or regular FTP, accordingly with your needs)
5. Give your customers a copy of [Filezilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) or other FTP clients to upload and manage the files
6. Cross you finger and hope nobody will ever push the wrong button

Others possible alternatives are:

1. Linux APT server-side system. Can be used/tweaked but it is a clear overkill for our quite simple needs (and it is quite complicated).
2. A file exchange web application like http://boxroomapp.com/ , https://github.com/codyaray/sharebox or similar. Can be tweaked to fit the requirements but this require time.